# Pandas Sort MultiIndex Pivot Table

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, multi-index

Given the following pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'YYYYMM':[201603,201503,201403,201303,201603,201503,201403,201303],
         'Count':[5,6,2,7,4,7,8,9],
         'Group':['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B']})
df['YYYYMM']=df['YYYYMM'].astype(str).str[:-2].astype(np.int64)
t=df.pivot_table(df,index=['Group'],columns=['YYYYMM'],aggfunc=np.sum)
t
        Count
YYYYMM  2013    2014    2015    2016
Group               
A        7       2       6       5
B        9       8       7       4
```

I'd like to sort the rows (groups A and B) ascendingly by 2016 such that group B is above group A, while retaining the overall layout of the pivot table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sort_values`

```
t.sort_values(('Count', 2016))
```

the tuple `('Count', 2016)` is the name of the column you want to sort by.

looks like:

```
       Count               
YYYYMM  2013 2014 2015 2016
Group                      
B          9    8    7    4
A          7    2    6    5
```